# Jquery AJAX JSONP not working

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, jsonp

First of all, I am very new to WebAPICore and JSONP and trying to get the JSON data from WebAPICore.

I have built the test API which returns JSON object and it's working fine in the Browser.  I did configure the CORS to allow cross origin access too.

I did the test JSONP call as shown in
https://www.sitepoint.com/jsonp-examples/

Working Code as shown in the Example

```
  $.getJSON("https://api.github.com/users/jeresig?callback=?", function (json) {
      console.log(json);
  });
```

Not working even though it did return the JSON data back

```
  $.getJSON("http://localhost:1569/offerings/5?callback=?", function (json) {
      console.log(json);
  });
```

I am getting the 'Unexpected token' error when calling my service.

I couldn't figure out why it's not working only with my service.  Please see the following image about the errors, return jsons and Debugging in Chrome Console.

[image]

The only difference between GitHub API and my API is the formatting of JSONs.

Do I need to do special formatting or encoding in my service to return the JSON data for JSONP?

My Test code which returns JSON Object from WebAPICore

```
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public Offering Get(int id)
    {
        return new Offering()
        {
            OfferingID = id
            , CourseName = "TestCourse"
            , CourseCode = "TestCode"
            , Description = "My Description"
        };
    }
```

Comment: Just to clarify: You're not using JSONP. Your webservice returns JSON and your AJAX call requests JSON. There is nothing JSONP related to this question. Because you used CORS you wouldn't need it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has ever encountered this error... here is the working code:

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:1569/offerings/5',
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                }
            });
```

just change $.getJSON to traditional $.ajax call